# How to make .htaccess writeable for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, buddypress

I have Wordpress running on a dedicated centos server with Buddypress installed . Buddypress requires pretty permalinks. Therefore I changed i to /%postname%.

Somehow it did not work because Buddypress is not working correctly and Wordpress suggests to create the .htaccess myself :

*"If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all."*

I have tried every hint I found but somehow it does not work. Here is a list:

- mod_rewirte is enabled
- .htaccess was created and filled with wordpress suggested information
- .htaccess was set to chmod 777
- FollowSymLinks and AllowOverride All was set in the httpd.conf

Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is this question closed? It's not a question about "general computing hardware and software." He's not asking for recommendations or what's best. It's a very specific issue.

Answer (score 12):

None of those things will make a difference if your `ownership` is wrong. The reason wordpress can't write to it is because the file is probably owned by another user instead of web server. I've seen this numerous times.

To fix this issue, first change the permission back to a *more* secure permission using this from the command line.

```
chmod 644 .htaccess
```

Then change the ownership/group of the .htaccess file to web server user.

For CentOS/RHEL

```
chown apache: .htaccess
```

For Ubuntu/Debian

```
chown www-data: .htaccess
```

Now wordpress should be able to right to this file.

Comment: its sickening. Sometimes it works other times it doesn't

Comment: Doesn't work in all the cases.

Comment: @BiratBose there are different server configurations for other people. Just because it didn't work for you, no need to down vote it. It does work for most people. You probably didn't do something right.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.htaccess` file permissions to `644`.
It should help.

Comment: It is also possible to use   sudo chmod -R 777 <path to wordpress folder >/

Comment: ^^^Yikes...don't do that